# regular expression , get text between two symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to get text between two symbols. Regex too tough for me.
Here is the string

```
" Hello my {{name}} , I'm from /# singapore {{city}} #/". I text between "/# - #/"
```

Here how I tried , but it doesnt work `\#[\w]+\#`. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following pattern: `\/#(.+)#\/`

Explanation:

`\/#` - match `/#` literally

`(.+)` - match one or more of any characters and store it inside capturing group

`#\/` = match `#/` literally

```js
var txt = "Hello my {{name}} , I'm from /# singapore {{city}} #/ adasdwq";
var match = txt.match("\/#(.+)#\/");
console.log(match);
```

Comment: Whitespace can be used to trim word/sentence : `\/#\s?(.+)\s?#\/` (just a suggestion) :) Oh, actually, that doesn't work that well in case of multiple spaces...

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and join

```js
var a='/#name#/';
console.log(a.split('/#').join('').split('#/').join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
const text = 'xxxx #needIt# xxxx';
const needText = text.match(/(?<=\#).*(?=\#)/)[0];
console.log(needText)
```

Comment: see here https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#quantifiers